# Using kernel32 in .Net

Tags: c#, c++, interop

Question for the SO community.  I have a C++ library with full source code and I am able to compile it in 32- and 64-bit mode.  However, to call the code from .NET, I must choose either 32- or 64-bit, therefore forcing my application to be either 32- or 64-bit.  I decided that I may have to live with that problem... but I stumbled across something that gives me hope.  I noticed that I can reference "kernel32.dll" in an extern function and the program runs just fine in both 32- and 64-bit.  Does anyone know how this is done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a feature of Windows on Windows 64 (WOW64): the [File System Redirector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384187.aspx)

You can't really use it for your own libraries, because it's only for the System32 folder. (Do **NOT** even *think* about putting your DLLs in System32.)

Using [SetDllDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686203.aspx) might help, but I'm not sure.

Comment: That's perfect!  SetDllDirectory will work by merely setting it to either x86 or x64 at runtime.  I just tried it and it works like a charm.  Thanks so much!